# Handle bars don’t return

Tags: steering

My 27 year old Raleigh had the very first Rock Shox on them. I replaced with a set that cost about $160. I also upgraded the head set with a new style clamp on stem. Everything felt great until I rode and found that when I turn, the handle bars want to stay and it takes some force to return them to the straight position. I adjusted the headset so the turning is very smooth on the work stand but again the headset feels like it wants to flop to either side. The front wheel is a lot further forward than the original Rock Shox.

Comment: As a hacky fix to try and restore the geometry, you might try a smaller front wheel, or a larger rear wheel assuming it fits and has disk brakes.  But that would mean a 24" or 22" front wheel which is going to look and handle differently itself.

Comment: Perhaps a rebuild of the original fork would have been a better plan ?  If you still have the original, this may be a solution too.

Answer (score 5):

Your steering geometry has obviously been messed up by the installation of the new fork.

I'm guessing the new fork is longer than the old fork.

An old RockShox suspension fork would have very little (by modern standards) travel, and the distance from axle to bottom of the head tube would not be much greater than a rigid fork. Modern forks have longer travel, are designed for bikes with higher head tubes and are significantly longer. if you put a longer fork on a frame it pushes the head tube up, increases the head angle and positions the front wheel too far forward.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [wheel flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_geometry#Wheel_flop). Make sure you understand what your changes did to the steering geometry in terms of rake and trail.